# error propagation not working in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a script which goes as below...

some function definitions on top and one of them is...

```
function err_out    
{

 trap 'echo "ERROR in $STEP function. EXITING!";exit 1' ERR    
 #some more messages

 exit 1
}

# Main program starts here
trap 'err_out' ERR

#do something
#call some functions
#call cleanup function
#end of script
```

when ever some error happens in the functions, they are not propagated and err_out function is not called.

I tried **#!/bin/bash -E** too; that way when there is an error the script exits but what I need is error to be propagated properly to the handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `bash` info page:

> All other aspects of the shell execution environment are identical
>   between a function and its caller with these exceptions: the `DEBUG`
>   and `RETURN` traps are not inherited unless the function has been given
>   the `trace` attribute using the `declare` builtin or the `-o functrace`
>   option has been enabled with the `set` builtin, (in which case all
>   functions inherit the `DEBUG` and `RETURN` traps), and the `ERR` trap
>   is not inherited unless the `-o errtrace` shell option has been enabled.

So you need to `set -o errtrace` at the top of the script for the `ERR` trap to be propagated into your functions.

Additionally, you need to be careful about that recursive `ERR` trap in `err_out`.  Did you really want to set a new trap in the error handler, or did you want to display that message?  If the latter, just `echo` it; the `trap` would only be invoked if an error occurred in your error handler.

Comment: Yes, but the original poster mentioned that he tried `#!/bin/bash -E` and the bash manpage mentions: `-o errtrace: Same as -E.`.
So the problem seems to be something else.

Comment: See the "Additionally".  `-E`/`errprint` is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: OK - I see, you're right.

Comment: Excellent. It works as expected. Thanks a lot geekosaur